# Method "getExternalFilesDirs" added to blacklist

Tags: android-studio

[image: Screenshot]

I'm doing an application and I've accidentally clicked a command and put my method on a blacklist. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome! I can't tell what you are asking. From what I can see, it seems to be doing what you are saying. Please clarify.

Comment: What about that "Undo" link at the end of the line?

Comment: Can not press Undo because it is text